# Formula not working for conditional formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm trying to setup a formula for a conditional format.

Here's what I want to do:

For any row in column D that has a value different than the same row in column C, highlight the value in Row D

Some of the values are text so I only want this formula to work for values that are numeric.

This is the formula I came up with:

```
=ISNUMBER(AND($D2:$D1308,$D2<>$C2))
```

Unfortunately, it's not working. I'm not sure where I went wrong. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER($D2),$D2<>$C2)
```

Comment: @christopherjc We all go down wrong paths and need new eyes sometimes.  Just come back in ten minutes and mark as correct, please.